# Housekeeping before upgrading to new OSX

Tags: time-machine, macos

I would like to go for a fresh install, but I've got GB's of Mail archives, iCloud Photos, etc. Therefore I always end up doing just the upgrade on top of the existing OS.

This time I would like to spend sometime to go for a fresh install, then restore mail archives and photos. Can time machine help me with this? Any guides as to how?

Comment: I think that you'd just be better off by upgrading on top of the existing version of OS. It'd be a lot of trouble to backup everything to Time Machine and then erase the drive and reinstall OS X on it, then reinstate the backup. Plus, I'm not convinced that a fresh install would install that much faster than a regular one. So, if it were me, I'd just install OS X over the existing version of OS X like I always do.

Comment: @RedEagle2000, I think a clean install is the right thing now and then. Is removes lots of 'forgotten' settings files, logs, unused preferences as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly *possible* to backup your drive with Time Machine (or SuperDuper or whatever) wipe it and start fresh. This is something that is commonly done with Windows PCs as they continue to be subject to "bit rot" or the inevitable slowdown of a Windows system after a few years of use.

I, personally, have been just upgrading in place since back when the Macintosh Operating System was called "System #" and have rarely found that a clean install did much except take up a bunch of time. However other folks may have different experiences. It all depends on what you use your Mac for and what is installed on it.

If you have a nice fast USB 3 or Thunderbolt drive you could try installing the OS fresh on that and see if you see any real change (not attributable to it being an external device) in performance when booted from that fresh install.

Note that USB 2 drives **will** be slower and depending on the chipset and drive used in the USB 3 or Thunderbolt enclosure there will already be a performance hit, so take any results with a grain of salt.

Me, if I had to do a clean install, I would image my boot drive to an external drive. Wipe the partition and install the OS **and apps** fresh. Then use Migration Assistant to bring over your user settings/documents, leaving the apps installed on the old boot drive behind for the fresh installs on the fresh install of the OS. And allowing Migration Assistant to *only* bring over your settings and files.

Comment: I am a web developer, and I install random tools to try, but when I uninstall they don't really go away completely, isn't it?

Now that I know which software to keep, I thought of going for a fresh install and Install only the ones I need.

Is there any app that can help me with clean up?

Comment: Generally if the tool is a Mac app that you drag to the Applications folder you can usually uninstall it by just deleting it. There are often a few settings files left behind (preference files) usually found in ~/Library/Preferences. There are a number of uninstaller apps available for the Mac. I would search macupdate.com for "uninstaller" to find an app that would help with this.